# How can I see full htdocs on LAN server

Tags: windows-7, apache-http-server, xampp

I have installed xampp on FileServer. The OS is Win7 and then I shared htdocs for everyone.

When I use another computer in the same LAN to visit \\FileServer\htdocs with explorer.exe, some of the files and folders are invisible. How can I make all of the files and folders visible?

===edit 1===

If a guest upload pictures from server, these new files will miss permissions to Everyone so LAN can't see.

Comment: Have you compared the permissions of the "hidden" files and folders to ensure that the user connecting actually has permissioins? The "sharing" feature may not have recursively changed the permissions if the user didn't have permission to change permissions on the particular item.

Comment: I compared the permissions. The hidden files didn't have permissions for Eveyone. How can I let the new upload pictures grant permissions automatically?

Comment: This answer solved my problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851821/setting-file-permissions-in-windows-with-php/23857310#23857310

Comment: Are you talking about samba / windows file sharing (`\\FileServer\htdocs`)? If so, why tag or even mention apache / xampp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851821/setting-file-permissions-in-windows-with-php/23857310#23857310

1.Search upload_tmp_dir in php.ini

2.upload_tmp_dir="D:\xampp\tmp"

3.Set D:\xampp\tmp permissions to Everyone